# Python regular expression match multiple words anywhere

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python's regular expression to match a string with several words.
For example, the string is "These are oranges and apples and pears, but not pinapples or .." The list of words I want to find is 'and', 'or' and 'not'. No matter the order or the position.

I tried `r'AND | OR | NOT` 
but didn't work.

Also tried `r'.*?\bAND\b.*?\bOR\b.*?\bNOT\b.*?$`
still didn't work...

Not good at regular expression.. 
And hint?
Thanks!

Comment: do you want to capture them or just detect that they are there?

Comment: If you simply need to check for the presence, use `in`. For e.g  `[word in 'These are oranges and apples and pears, but not pinapples or ..' for word in ['or', 'and', 'not']]
[True, True, True]`

Comment: @Cfreak Capture them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You've got a few problems there.

First, matches are case-sensitive unless you use the `IGNORECASE`/`I` flag to ignore case. So, `'AND'` doesn't match `'and'`.

Also, unless you use the `VERBOSE`/`X` flag, those spaces are part of the pattern. So, you're checking for `'AND '`, not `'AND'`. If you wanted that, you probably wanted spaces on each side, not just those sides (otherwise, `'band leader'` is going to match…), and really, you probably wanted `\b`, not a space (otherwise a sentence starting with `'And another thing'` isn't going to match).

Finally, if you think you need `.*` before and after your pattern and `$` and `^` around it, there's a good chance you wanted to use `search`, `findall`, or `finditer`, rather than `match`.

So:

```
>>> s = "These are oranges and apples and pears, but not pinapples or .."
>>> r = re.compile(r'\bAND\b | \bOR\b | \bNOT\b', flags=re.I | re.X)
>>> r.findall(s)
['and', 'and', 'not', 'or']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ghrZ6k10KqthhhrG)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\band\b|\bor\b|\bnot\b", "These are oranges and apples and pears, but not pinapples or ..")
['and', 'and', 'not', 'or']
```

a|b means match either a or b

\b represents a word boundary

re.findall(pattern, string) returns an array of all instances of pattern in string

Comment: What is the `{1}` adding here? A pattern always matches one copy of itself unless you specify otherwise. Also, `{n}` binds very tightly than `|`, so even if it were useful, it's only going to affect the `t`, not the whole alternation. Also, I'm pretty sure he doesn't want to match the `or` in `oranges`, hence all the spaces and `\b` stuff.