# In pandas, check if a master string contains a string from a list, if it does remove the substring from the master string and add it to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1=
    A    
0   Black Prada zebra leather Large   
1   green Gucci striped Canvas small   
2   blue Prada Monogram calf leather XL

df2=
    color    pattern   material     size
0   black    zebra     leather      small
1   green    striped   canvas       xl
2   yellow   checkered calf leather medium
3   orange   monogram
4   white    plain
5            pinstripe
```

I want to compare the columns in df2 with df1 (controlling for non-uniform case and white space) and, if there is a match, put the match in a new column in df1 and remove it from A. It should be a complete match so that "calf leather" doesn't mistakenly get matched with "leather." So the result would be only the non-matched substrings left in A:

```
df3=
    A            color    pattern   material     size
0   Prada Large  black    zebra     leather      NaN
1   Gucci        green    striped   canvas       small
2   Prada        blue     Monogram  calf leather XL
```

I have tried using for loops, but my dataset is quite large and I feel like that's not utilizing pandas fully. I have also tried contains and isin with no success. Is the only solution to use .extract and convert df2 columns to regex? Thanks!

Comment: Is that an error in the first row of your example df1? `Prada Large`? I don't quite get what you are getting at with your data.

Comment: I changed the name of the desired output to df3 to avoid confusion. However, df3 is really just df1 with more columns added and the strings that are added to those columns removed from the string in column "A"

Comment: How are the missing values represented in your data?

Comment: If you are referring to rows 3, 4, 5 in df2 where some values are missing, they are simply blank. In my real DataFrame, I have dozens of sizes but only a few materials, for example.

Comment: I can take a look at this again tomorrow if nobody has answered it by then, but I might suggest doing a clean-up of the data prior to merging them, so you don't have to deal with matching `calf` to `calf leather`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

It sounds like you may want to rank the way you are searching the columns of `df2` from `df1` (I'm calling that `search` now below).

Here it checks what the maximum percentage of the words in your `search` string match with words in the columns of `df2`. If it meets some required threshold, then it is removed.

I've tested it and it is working, but you may need to play a bit with the regex matching.

```
import pandas

def perc_match(src, s):
    '''Return percentage of words in s found in src'''
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/26985301/943773
    import re
    s = ' | '.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in s.split()])
    r = re.compile(s, flags=re.I | re.X)

    return len(r.findall(src))/len(src)


search = ['Black Prada zebra leather Large',
          'green Gucci striped Canvas small',
          'blue Prada Monogram calf leather XL']

d2 = {'color':['black', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'white',''],
      'pattern':['zebra', 'striped', 'checkered', 'monogram', 'plain',
                 'pinstripe'],
      'material':['leather', 'canvas', 'calf leather','','',''],
      'size':['small', 'xl', 'medium','','','']}

df2 = pandas.DataFrame(d2)

# Strip whitespace and make all lower case
strip_lower = lambda x: x.strip().lower()
search = list(map(strip_lower, search))
df2 = df2.applymap(strip_lower)

# Combine all columns to single string for each row
df2['full_str'] = df2.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row), axis=1)

# Min percent matching
min_thresh = 0.1

# Calculate the percentage match for each row of dataframe
rm_ind = list()
for i in range(len(search)):
    s = search[i]
    # If you want you could save these `perc_matches` for later
    perc_matches = df2['full_str'].apply(perc_match, args=(s,))
    # Mark for removal if above threshold
    if perc_matches.max() > min_thresh:
        rm_ind.append(i)

# Remove indices from `search`
for i in rm_ind:
    del search[i]
```

Comment: Not working because the column name of df1 has no relationship to df2, so it gives a key error on 'A', the column name that does not exist in df2.

Comment: Your re-creation of df1 is not correct. "Brand" is not known (part of the reason for removing matched substrings - so "brand" can be inferred once other known attributes are removed). df1 is a single series of strings and df2 is a DataFrame of several lists of known attributes that I want to search df1 for.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't parse `df1` into columns if each row/string has a consistent structure?

Comment: And how is your data propagated into `df1`? Again, I think your data should be in a cleaner state before doing your comparison/merge.

Comment: the data in df1 is the result of a web scrape, so it is not consistent. Thus, breaking df1 into columns based on whitespace would not help (as far as I know) because multi-word attributes would get lost.

Comment: Essentially, I want to pull info out of df1 in categories that I know and then be able to look at what is left behind after everything I know has been removed.

Comment: So the modification of `df2` is not so important? You want to match any of the entries in a row/string from `df` (e.g. `blue Prada Monogram calf leather XL`) in any of the columns of `df2`, and remove that row/string. AND `blue Prada Monogram calf leather XL` could just as likely be `blue calf leather XL Prada Monogram`?

Comment: That's correct. df2 is not being modified - it is a key of known values, so to speak.